# Turning Integers Into Factors In R Creates Null Values Instead

Tags: r, null, integer, factors

I'm trying to change fields in my data from integers to factors as they represent descriptive data (innings, outs, etc.).

```
str(InitTrainData[,10:14])
'data.frame':   1097726 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ inning    : int  1 7 9 7 1 7 9 3 3 4 ...
 $ top_bottom: int  2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ outs      : int  0 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ balls     : int  3 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 3 ...
 $ strikes   : int  2 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 1 0 ...
```

When I try to change them to factors they are turned to null values. Any idea why or how to avoid this?

```
InitTrainData[,10:14] <- as.factor(InitTrainData[,10:14])
> str(InitTrainData[,10:14])
'data.frame':   1097726 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ inning    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ top_bottom: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ outs      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ balls     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ strikes   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `InitTrainData[10:14] <- lapply(InitTrainData[10:14], factor)`. Your data is a data.frame, you must coerce to factor column by column.

Comment: You are correct. I've applied the transformation individually and found success. Thanks!